# Redis - Master - Master Sync without sharding

Tags: redis

I'm currently using redis in a master -slave scenario.  In my case i use redis as some kind of CacheBus and I want ot eliminate the single point of failure (if the master server goes down)

Is there a way to configure redis to sync 2 Masters with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and because SE requires 30 characters in the body I'll just add this.